# NSFetchedResultsController order not changed when it should

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` (or NSFRC) that is really pretty standard;

- No predicate set
- Fetch all items of one entity kind
- Sorted by a `NSDate` field (descending)
- Delegate is set
- Data is fetched

Up next the data gets updated:

- A background thread updates the data
- the field used in the sort order gets changed among with other fields.
- The changes are merged into the main threads' ObjectContext
- The `NSFRC` nicely passes on the changes to the TableView, **except for the order changes**.
- Is doesn't matter if I animate changes, or simply do `reloadData()`, data is changed, the order isn't.

I would expect the delegate for example to swap the first and second row because the second row's date value is now higher than the first one.

If I re-open the ViewController (so the fetch is done again on a new VC and `NSFRC`) the order does change as expected. But thats anything but intuitive for the user.

Could anyone please point me into possible places to search for my mistake?

**Just to reiterate:**

- Changes to content are being delegated, i.e. another field contains text, which does get changed.
- The order is not being changed. So it appears the SortOrder is only used when fetching the very first time.

---

Here's two screenshots, the second line (date) is also the sort order. The second image shows updated data but a wrong sort order.

### Before

[image: Situation before the data update]

### After

[image: Situation after the data update]

Comment: What is the code that is updating the tableview when your changes get merged?

Comment: Added it to the question, although I have a feeling this isn't the problem?

Comment: Why did you add all those optional bindings? Don't you trust the code in the Apple template? The documentation states clearly in which cases the index paths are `nil`.

Comment: In your post you say Data is fetched, then delegate is set. Is it really happening in that order? If the data is fetched before the delegate is set, it wont update. Have you confirmed your delegate methods are actually being called and doing what you want via breakpoints?

Comment: @vadian: I tried several different ways. This code worked before so I'm not sure this is the problem.

Comment: @WillM. : Thats the problem, they are being called to refresh items (content of the cells gets updated just fine). But the order seems be stuck on the 'old' ordering, regardless of if the order should change. I.E. row 2 should become row 1 and update its' content. It just stays in place but does update the content.

Comment: The optional bindings don't cause the problem, I know, but they are completely useless. Depending on the type all passed index paths are never `nil`.

Comment: Perhaps, I've had problems with it before. It's also used in a lot of examples found online (such as http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-25072). Either way, it doesn't seem to the right thing to focus on here :).

Comment: Even if I just do `reloadData()`, the order is not being preserved, so that rules out some possibilities. I updated the question and added screenshots

Comment: The reordering is performed by calling  `didChangeObject` and passing the `Move` type. Is `didChangeObject` called at all after changing a record? Regarding the online tutorial: Before blindly trusting those half-knowledge tutorials read (or at least compare) the code in the sample projects provided by Apple.

Comment: @vadian: I did, and like I said before the delegate code works fine in other screens with a similar setup. Even if I just run `reloadData()` (so all records are update) the order isn't fixed. If I do use the controller delegate and animate the changes, `Move` is being called and moves the two rows. Content is updated and since the NSFRC still says the order is the same, the content is wrongly replaced (so it's back to square one).

Answer (score -1):

When your data changes you may need to nil the `NSFRC` and let it do its thing. For example. Lets say that you have a function which changes the order of your items. If you are using standard Apple code, you should have something like this

```
func updateSort () {

    _fetchedResultsController = nil //Here is the magic
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Core Data
var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    // do your basic initialization and set the delegate and return it

    return _fetchedResultsController!

}

 var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

Comment: The whole idea of `NSFRC` delegation is it can tell you those changes. I don't change the data/order myself. The records in CoreData get updated, that should trigger re-ordering but it doesn't.